# How to fly with a spider

Tags: air-travel, pets

I'll be visiting Brazil soon, and a friend of mine in Mexico City is a bit of an arachnophile, and has asked me to return with a [Brazilian Whiteknee Tarantula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazilian_whiteknee_tarantula) for her.  I realize there are likely legal obstacles to doing this, but lets assume that I have that all worked out. (Legal question [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/25810/444).)

Practically, how can one fly with a tarantula, without injuring the animal, and without scaring the !@#$% out of airline staff?

If it matters, it would be roughly a 15-hour transit, with a 1.5-hour flight followed by a 10-hour flight.

Comment: Why would you think that cutie is going to scare anyone? I expect people asking you to cuddle up with it!

Comment: Make sure you put it on a leash when you take it for a walk through the cabin!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every airline will have its own policies, so **contact your airline and ask**.  Airlines regularly transport all sorts of weird creatures, up to and including [a herd of elephants](http://www.gadling.com/2012/06/10/airline-transports-herd-of-african-elephants-photos/), so they'll be happy to advise you how to deal with a tarantula.

Comment: Ironically, I'll be flying with the same airline in that story.