# What are the legal implications of exporting a tarantula from Brazil to Mexico?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, brazil, mexico, pets

I'm not sure if this fits on this site or not, since it boils down to a question about animal import/export.

As mentioned [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/25809/444), a Mexican friend has requested a rather odd souvenir from Brazil: A [tarantula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazilian_whiteknee_tarantula).

What are the legal implications for export from Brazil, and import into Mexico if I were to try to fulfill her request?  Is this even legal?

Comment: "I've had it with this m********g tarantulas on this m********g plane?"  At least they don't seem to be an endangered species.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yours spider is not listed by [CITES](http://www.speciesplus.net/species), so it is not forbidden to bring your pet to one of the member states if you comply with the [local](http://www.aphis.usda.gov/regulations/vs/iregs/animals/animal_mexico.shtml) import rules. It seems that your friend would need to apply for an import permit:

> For species not listed, the requirements are not known. However, exporters wanting to ship livestock or germplasm whose requirements are not listed above, should have the interested party (importer/buyer) in the country of destination apply for an Import Permit at the appropriate ministry. This Import Permit will most likely outline the specific requirements